# for each key after index "number" create table , key counter Twig

Tags: twig

I have a list of sortiments that contain shoe size and pair numbers, taken from a csv file with php and saved as an array in in Twig.

[image]

In twig this is my previous code to make a table. the problem here is, it is made to only make tables with 6 columns and not more or less.

```
<div class="twp-sortiment">
    {% for key in page.extensions.TwpSortiment.data %}
        {% set shoeSizeArray = key.shoesize|split(',') %}
        {% set sortimentArray = key.sortiment|split(',') %}

        {{ sortimentArray[2] }}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[3] }}</th>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[4] }}</th>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[5] }}</th>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[6] }}</th>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[7] }}</th>
                    <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[8] }}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[3] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[4] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[5] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[6] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[7] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ sortimentArray[8] }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As you can see i have put my rows in to arrays (shoeSizeArray, shoeSizeArray).
Now i would like to create the table based on how many keys come after index 2, starting from index 3, my table should take values and increase until its at the end. so i tried this but obviously doesnt work as i lack knowladge about Twig.

```
<div class="twp-sortiment">
    {% for key in page.extensions.TwpSortiment.data %}
        {% set shoeSizeArray = key.shoesize|split(',') %}
        {% set sshoeSizeArray = key.sortiment|split(',') %}
        {{ sortimentArray[2] }}
                    <table>
        <tr>
            {% for key in shoeSizeArray %}
                {% set counter = ( counter | default(2) ) + 1 %}
                <th>{{ shoeSizeArray[counter] }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for key in sortimentArray %}
                {% set counter = ( counter | default(2) ) + 1 %}
                <td>{{ sortimentArray[counter] }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see I get 3 more emtpy table columns because im counting every key but I dont want the first 3 keys to be counted in my "for loop",now I have to say count the key of array - 3 `(for till index 2:  [0],[1],[2])` and then do the  and  for that amount of

Number of the keyCounter -3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use slice with split filter https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html

**like**

```
{% set shoeSizeArray = key.shoesize|split(',')|slice(3) %} 
{% set sortimentArray = key.sortiment|split(',')|slice(4) %}
```

Comment: Thanks !! besides that i had to remove the counters and use {{key}}. ur slice on second line is 4 it should be 3 :D have a nice day sir :).

Comment: yeah, i didn't count, anyway you can alter :)

Comment: no worries man :D been working with twig for a week now and dont know how many functionalities they have.

Comment: Nothing much, it is template engine. Most of the features in it are for display, you should not refine data in twig template, ideally you should eliminate unwanted data in your data model and display in template.